# How to edit the sharepoint 2016 page layout

Tags: sharepoint-server, sharepoint-foundation, 2016, page-layout

I have a custom page layout in my existing site and every new pages created in the site is currently using the new custom page layout. Initially when creating the custom page I have added a contact email address to the bottom of the page. Now the email address has changed, and I would like to update the new email address to the custom page layout.

If I download the custom page layout file from  the "master page & page layout" gallery, edit it in notepad++ and upload it back to the library and publish will the pages currently using the layout reflect this change? Alternatively, can anyone suggest a simple way to update the email label on the layout and have every page reflect that?

Comment: Yes, it will work. Existing pages using this page layout will be updated. Make sure you check-in/publish/approve the page layout after uploading updated page layout to master pages/page layouts gallery.

Comment: voted to reopen since now the question is much clearer than before.